# Is there a way to get all the internal storage data from my LG W30 which doesnt turn on?

Tags: data-recovery, lg, data-transfer, internal-sd, data-connection

My android phone **LG W30** fell pretty bad from a decent height and it doesn't turn on now. No response from any buttons. when connected to power, the indicator LED turns on and nothing else. This is the current situation of my phone.

I would like to retrieve all the data from the internal storage. I tried to connect it to my PC, but the device isn't getting recognized. Is there any way that i can transfer my data? Please help

Comment: Your device was release 2019 with Android 9. This means that all you data is encrypted by default and can't be decrypted without the CPU of your device in a working state.

Comment: oh ok. thank you for the quick response